# Mouse/Keybord events full screen html5 video (javascript/jquery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, video, fullscreen

Is it possible to set onmouseup, onmousedown, onclick etc. functions on a video element that is fullscreen, using webkitRequestFullScreen?  I register them for the element when I create it, but I do not appear to get the events when the video is full screen.

Also, is it possible to stop the video progress bar appearing when in full screen mode whenever I move the mouse?

Any answers welcome, either using jquery or javascript, or similar.

Comment: how are you using fullscreen? if you are using mozilla...

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Using_fullscreen_mode

Comment: I am using webkitRequestFullScreen in Google Chrome.  I have tried setting the onmouseup, onmousedown etc. functions on the video element, and these work when not-fullscreen.  When fullscreen these events do not seem to fire.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find a way to listen to mouse events on fullscreen as well,
but I've found a workaround:

Instead of putting the video on fullscreen, I simply change the video CSS to:

```
position: fixed;
left: 0px;
top: 0px;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
z-index: 999;
```

Video then behaves like it's on fullscreen, and everything works as usual.

Answer (score 0):

Finally found a way to do it in Chrome: wrap your `video` element with `div` and call `webkitRequestFullScreen()` for that `div` rather then for `video` + some additional magic will be required.
HTML code snippet:

```
<div id="video-container" style="background-color: #000000;" onclick=divClicked()>
    <video id="myvideo">Video not supported!</video>
</div>
```

JavaScript code snippet:

```
function doFullscreen() {
    var container = document.getElementById("video-container");

    if (container.requestFullscreen) {
        container.requestFullscreen();
    } else if (container.mozRequestFullScreen) {
        container.mozRequestFullScreen();
    } else if (container.webkitRequestFullscreen) {
        container.webkitRequestFullscreen();
    }

    var video = document.getElementById("myvideo");

    // have to resize the video to fill the whole screen
    video.width=window.screen.availWidth;
    video.height=window.screen.availHeight;
}
```

Such approach allows handling mouse/etc. events in `div` element - see `onclick` declaration at HTML example above.
Also note that such approach doesn't force video controls to appear either on fullscreen or in windowed mode.

For the second question regarding the progress bar you can add the following to your CSS:

```
video::-webkit-media-controls-enclosure {
  display:none;
}
```

But note once again that it is not needed when using the approach above.